# Directive wont work in IE11

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I encounter some troubles with this directive in IE11 (note : on Edge, Chrome et Firefox, everything works fine).

If I place an alert just before returning the object, i dont have it in IE, and I got twice in other browser (but it's ok anyway).

Angular version is 1.5.3

```
.directive("cartBtnQty", function($rootScope) {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope :{
        articleQuantity: '@', 
        lineNumber: '@'
    },
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, form) {
        alert('directive');
        elem.bind('click keydown', function (e) {

            $operator = null;

            // click button +/-
            $operator = angular.element(e.target).data('operator')
            if($operator == '+')
                scope.articleQuantity = parseInt(scope.articleQuantity)+1;
            else if($operator == '-' && scope.articleQuantity > 1)
                scope.articleQuantity = parseInt(scope.articleQuantity)-1;

            // limitation pour quantité négative
            if(scope.articleQuantity < 1)
                scope.articleQuantity = parseInt(1);


            if((e.type == 'click' && ($operator == '-' || $operator == '+')) || e.type == 'keydown'){
                $rootScope.cartQtyItem({articleQuantity:scope.articleQuantity, lineNumber:scope.lineNumber});
                return true;
            }
        });
    },

    template: '<div class="ui right mini action input">'+
                '<form><input type="text" ng-model="articleQuantity" ng-init="articleQuantity=articleQuantity" class="w30"/>'+
                '<div class="ui icon buttons mini">'+
                '<button class="ui button" data-operator="+"><i class="plus icon" data-operator="+"></i></button>'+
                '<button class="ui button grey" data-operator="-"><i class="minus icon" data-operator="-"></i></button>'+
                '</div></form></div>'
};
```

})

Comment: did you checked whether your file is included in the web application(check your js files whether its loaded or not in ie), because IE having limitation on number of external files to include

Comment: Yep, I place one alert on the head of my angular-directive.js file, and it work.

Comment: check your html, you may need to simply change `<cart-btn-qty></cart-btn-qty>` to `<div cart-btn-qty></div>` or `<div class="cart-btn-qty"></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aleksey Solovey was good. I switch the  to a proper class, and the old developer add some isIe() functions in the DOM. Thank you for your time guys.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues:

- missing variable declaration (btw, you shouldn't use $ for local variable) `var $operator = null`
- try to use `attr` instead of `data`:  `angular.element(e.target).attr('data-operator');`

alert should work just fine in IE in terms of this directive.

#
https://plnkr.co/edit/WqsPQxgkwCLEPMnaEANx?p=preview